# Dockerfile with autorestart

Tags: docker, image, restart

Can I write such Dockerfile, images from which will produce containers with autorestart?

I want to write Dockerfile and push it to repository. When someone gets this Dockerfile from repo and build from it image and runs containers from this image, these containers should be autorestartable (like if it was created with args --restart always)